# Laravel - React component Does not like importing comps in other comps

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, react-laravel

Hey I'm super new to Laravel and finally was able to get a react component to show up on the screen. however when I import another component for example.

`import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import SelectInput from "../components/SelectInput"
import React from "react"
export default class Head extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                header
                <SelectInput />
            </div>
        )
    }
}ReactDOM.render(<Head />, document.getElementById("Head"))`

```
//test
import React from "react"
import styled from "styled-components"

const Container = styled.container``

class SelectInput extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div>test</div>
    }
}

export default SelectInput
```

[Compiler Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DilLf.png)
[DevTools Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6MFC.png)

heres my Babelrc File. `{
    "presets": [
        [
            "env",
            {
                "modules": false
            }
        ],
        "react"
    ],
    "plugins": ["babel-plugin-transform-class-properties"]
}`

It will render the component when Im not trying to import `Test` but when its uncommented it will render nothing on the screen.  could it be Laravel doesn't compile it? any thoughts on what it may be?

I'm on Laravel 5.5.44

Comment: try: class Head extends React.Component

Comment: Seems to be the same issue. I added it to one then both components. *edit there is also no errors in the console.

Comment: have you imported React ? import React from 'react';

Comment: Yeah everythings imported ```import React from "react"
export default class Head extends React.Component {``` * in dev tools the ID and Script show up. they just dont render anything

Comment: post your test component as well

Comment: alright I edited the Question with <Test/>

Comment: Change this import Test from "../components/SelectInput" to import SelectInput from "../components/SelectInput" and then in render <SelectInput/>

Comment: Alright edited the post to what I have now. still nothing

Comment: are you getting any error?
in console run command: npm run watch

Comment: ```npm run watch``` is running and I get a compiled successfully. :(

Comment: i need to see you code..
there is something wrong...!

Comment: Yeah it took me so long to get the route in general up lol. I just posted some images of the compiler as well as the devtools. Here is the link i followed to get things working https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-react-app-with-laravel-backend-part-2-react--cms-29443

Comment: Looks like my error was having styled components within. If anyone has this issue I fixed it by downlaoding `babel-plugin-styled-components` then adding `"babel-plugin-styled-components",
   {
    "displayName": false
   }` to my babel.rc file Thanks Salman for helping out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like my error was having styled components within. If anyone has this issue I fixed it by downlaoding babel-plugin-styled-components then adding "babel-plugin-styled-components", { "displayName": false } to my babel.rc file Thanks Salman for helping out